# additional params in Jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using [Devbridge / jquery autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).

i have been trying to send additional parameters in ajax using its option `params` which is listed [In manual](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)

**Issue** :
it does not send the correct input values to ajax request. Instead it sends **initial state value of form inputs except the autocomplete input**. ( you can check that in console )

i have tired to reproduce the same [Here in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mdx9jnw/1/).

other thing i tried is

```
    onSearchStart: function (query) {
    $('#doc').autocomplete().setOptions({params :$("form").serialize()});
}
```

**From manual**
`onSearchStart: function (query) {}` called before ajax request. this is bound to input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'params' parameter has to be an object:

```
onSearchStart: function (query) {
    $('#doc').autocomplete().setOptions({params: {parameterA: $("form").serialize()}});
}
```

Comment: though this is not the complete answer (converted form ip name-val to object since i have CSRF in form and cant send it as parameterA ) but a good catch and acceptable. +1 for that. thanks mate.